# What is "!" in Dart Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, operators, operator-keyword

I know ! is used for NOT operation, but i find a code that use ! to fill variable with nullable type variable. When i read some code reference from internet i find this:

```
 NoteDetailPage(noteId: note.id!)
```

This is what it look like in NoteDetailPage:

```
const NoteDetailPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.noteId,
  }) : super(key: key);
```

note.id is a nullable int type and noteId is in int. If i go `noteId: note.id` then it will return conversion error `error: The argument type 'int?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.`, but when i plug !, it doesn't show any error

i tried to do a google search, but it says that "!" is for NOT operations, but I don't think it makes any sense to put NOT operations in that code. Does anyone know the function of "!" on that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the sign **!** is Bang operator in Dart.

By using ! operator, you are telling the compiler the variable won't be null.